# homebrew tap formula prefer_64_bit not found

Tags: homebrew

I do a tap and give me this error, I update brew and ruby and nothing.
Somebody can help me please?

```
> brew tap blackfireio/homebrew-blackfire

Updating Homebrew...
==> Auto-updated Homebrew!
Updated 1 tap (homebrew/cask).

==> Tapping blackfireio/blackfire
Cloning into '/usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/blackfireio/homebrew-blackfire'...
remote: Enumerating objects: 23, done.
remote: Counting objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (23/23), done.
remote: Total 23 (delta 15), reused 4 (delta 0), pack-reused 0
Unpacking objects: 100% (23/23), done.
Error: Invalid formula: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Taps/blackfireio/homebrew-blackfire/Formula/blackfire-agent.rb
blackfire-agent: undefined method `prefer_64_bit?' for OS::Mac:Module
Error: Cannot tap blackfireio/blackfire: invalid syntax in tap!
```

Answer (score 0):

I get the same error for a different formula https://github.com/GRASS-GIS/homebrew-grass-dev/issues/6 .  I **guess** something it is a bug in home-brew as it is defined in homebrerw https://www.rubydoc.info/github/Homebrew/brew/OS%2FMac:prefer_64_bit%3F - just started the build again...

It was a bug in home-brew - working again